# Subshell won't work as indented

Tags: bash, find, sed

I have some files like this:

```
├── abc.conf
├── def.conf
├── xyz.conf
├── 10-abc.conf.postix
├── 10-def.conf.postix
```

and I want to remove the `.postfix` from all files which starts with `10-`.
To do this without installing any tools, I tried to do this with `bash`, `find` and `sed`.

I built this:

```
$ find . -name "10-*.conf.postfix" -exec mv '{}' $(echo {} | sed -E 's/(.*)\.postfix$/\1/') \;
```

But it fails, because the `mv`-command will be rendered to this:

```
$ mv '10-abc.conf.postix' 10-abc.conf.postix
```

If I test the code inside of my subshell, then it works as expected (it returns the filename without the `.postifx`).
I'm not sure whats going wrong. Did you have a hint for me?

Comment: Sidenote: [use `printf '%s' {}` instead of `echo {}`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Subshells, like variables, **are processed before the whole command line is run.** The `$()` is interpreted by your parent shell, not by 'find', and no special treatment is given to 'find -exec' as 'find' itself is not a special shell construct but only a regular external command.

So the processing order looks like this:

1. The subshell `echo {} | sed -E 's/(.*)\.postfix$/\1/'` results in the output `{}`.
2. The command `find . -name "10-*.conf.postfix" -exec mv '{}' {} \;` runs.
3. When 'find' finds a matching file, it directly executes `mv` as a child process, replacing each {} argument with the found file name.

There are several alternatives to do what you want:

- Quoting the subshell so that it doesn't get expanded by the parent shell (either using single-quotes or backslash-escaping the `$`), **and** asking 'find' to run it through a shell afterwards (otherwise it wouldn't get expanded at all):

  ```
  find . -name "10-*.conf.postfix" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed -E "s/.../")"' -- {} \;
  ```

  This could be made shorter using `sed 's/\.postfix$//'`, as you're not really doing anything else than stripping the suffix. However, Bash's parameter expansion would make this even shorter using `${var%suffix}`:

  ```
  find . -name "10-*.conf.postfix" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.postfix}"' -- {} \;
  ```
- Using `perl-rename` (known as 'rename' on Debian), or other tools which can directly transform the source name without a subshell:

  ```
  find . -name "10-*.conf.postfix" -exec prename 's/\.postfix$//' {} \;
  ```

  If you don't need to include subdirectories, you can simply run:

  ```
  prename 's/\.postfix$//' 10-*.conf.postfix
  ```
- Using a `for` loop, which *is* a shell construct in which the processing of the body is delayed:

  ```
  for file in ./10-*.conf.postfix; do
      # mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed -E 's/(.*)\.postfix$/\1/')"
      # mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed 's/\.postfix$//')"
      mv "$file" "${file%.postfix}"
  done
  ```

  When using bash, you can enable `shopt -s globstar` and specify `**/*.conf.postfix` to match files recursively. As long as the amount of matches isn't huge, this is a good replacement for `find -name`.

  *(Note: Avoid using `for x in $(find)` unless you know precisely what it'll expand to.)*
- Using `vidir` or other interactive "directory editing" tools.